# How do I use my custom TeX distribution without anything reverting to the system-default one?

Tags: installing, environment-variables, texlive-2021

I just installed TeXLive to `/some/where/texlive/2021`. My system has a TL distribution installed, and obviously various paths will default to that one.

How do I set up my environment so that only my custom-installed TeXLive distribution gets used? I know there's more to it than just choosing the right binaries - there are hierarchies of folders which need to be chosen correctly, and maybe other issues.

I'm running a recent version of Linux; I'll add more details if necessary.

Comment: Make sure your custom TL comes first in the search PATH.

Comment: @daleif: Indeed, the `PATH` variable is one thing. I was assuming there is some recipe of settings... I remember TEXMFROOT plays some role. Or maybe there's some kind of script one could run?

Comment: Not on linux no. Linux dists assume you always get your stuff from them, but mostly we never get TL from Linux dists (or at least I never recommend it). I have this in my setup `export PATH=/opt/texlive/current/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH`, where `current` is a symbolic link. All my TeXLive installations live in `/opt/texlive/<year>/...` and `current` just points to one of these. When I don't really have to change much in otder to switch.

Comment: all the tex input paths are determined relative to the location of the binary so you only need to set PATH

Comment: @einpoklum ? doesn't latexml just call commands by name and rely on the current path? so if you set your PATH to an older texlive then latexmk will use that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Ignore my last comment, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### tl;dr: Add `/some/where/texlive/2021/` to your PATH variable

Luckily for you, you don't have to do that much: The TeXLive binaries notice their installation location, and look for relevant files and folders based on that location. However - they will *not* override the use of the `PATH` environment variable to locate *other* binaries.

So, if you installed to `/some/where/texlive/2021`,  the binaries will be in `/some/where/texlive/bin/x86_64-linux/` (or whatever your platform may be), and you'll want to write something like

```
export PATH="/some/where/texlive/bin/x86_64-linux/:$PATH"
```

(in bash shell syntax) for binaries to be properly located. And that's it.

Comment: it is much better to set the PATH variable than to use the binaries using an explict path. tex itself will work either way but  for example  if xetex launches xdvipdfmx in the backgropund or pdftex launches epstopdf in the background or makeindex or... then these will be found by the path and won't match the original executable, sometimes it works othertimes you will get weird compatibility mismatch errors

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Ah, that's an important point. So even though the binary knows where it is, it won't use that knowledge to invoke other binaries from the appropriate location?

Comment: That is not in its control, eg the `imakeindex` package uses shell-escape to call `makeindex` , the graphic[sx] packages if including eps into pdf shell out to call epstopdf  and these programs are found by the shell using standard path search if the package is doing `\immediate\write18{makeindex...` there is not much the tex binary can do about that (well it could have locally adjusted the path to add its own location, but it doesn't)